# How to do filter(in=...) using a different list for every object I do filter on in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm

I've written an implementation that explains what I mean. Is there a better way to do what I did?

```py
class Rstq(models.Model):
    pass


class Baz(models.Model):
    rstq_set = models.ManyToManyField(Rstq, blank=True)


class Foo(models.Model):
    # bar_set points to Bar because of many-to-many relationship

    def get_bars(self):
        bars = []
        for bar in self.bar_set:
            if bar.rstq not in bar.baz.rstq_set:
                bars.append(bar)
        return bars


class Bar(models.Model):
    baz = models.ForeignKey(Baz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rstq = models.OneToOneField(Rstq, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foo_set = models.ManyToManyField(Foo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, you can make use of an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to refer to a field, so:

```
from django.db.models import F

class Foo(models.Model):

    # …

    def get_bars(self):
        return self.bar_set.filter(baz__rstq_set=F('rstq')).distinct()
```

This yields a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT app_name_bar.*
FROM app_name_bar
INNER JOIN app_name_baz ON app_name_bar.baz_id = app_name_baz.id
INNER JOIN app_name_baz_rstq_set ON app_name_baz.id = app_name_baz_rstq_set.baz_id
WHERE app_name_baz_rstq_set.rstq_id = app_name_bar.rstq_id
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to filter by a field of a field, like a nested F expression?

Comment: @amlqrkgcgmtfpnupqy: no, you use double underscores, like in the key part, for example `baz_rstq_set=F('bla__bla2')`.

Comment: It generates invalid SQL: `SELECT ... WHERE ... IN "table"."foreign_id"`. That `"table"."foreign_id"` should be a list of that IDs not just a string if I understand correctly. What's wrong?

Comment: @amlqrkgcgmtfpnupqy: for the given query it works. Note that if you of course change it, the types should match, you can not compare a string with an int. So no, it should not be a list. If you make the models you define in your question, and run the query, it should work.

Comment: @amlqrkgcgmtfpnupqy: you can print the query with `print(queryset.query)`. If I run this locally, I get results. But perhaps you obfuscate too much.

Comment: Just noticed you compare sets instead of making sure the element is in the set.

Comment: @amlqrkgcgmtfpnupqy: but that is how a m2m filter works, since it makes JOINs, and you check for an equality in the JOIN.

Comment: Oh, correct, forget what I said. :) Thanks for the answer, I'll try to debug it further myself.

Comment: I've got what's wrong. `rstq_set` could be blank and I actually am doing `exclude` on that query rather than `filter`, forgot to mention it in the question. `if bar.rstq not in bar.baz.rstq_set` is correct.

Comment: @amlqrkgcgmtfpnupqy: ah, then it is `.exclude(..)` instead of `.filter(..)`.

Comment: Nope, I get zero results when `rstq_set` for that `baz` is empty. If I add other `Rstq` object to `rstq_set` that is not being referenced in `baz` it gets me correct result.

Comment: Sorry for misleading information in the previous edit.